# How to improve the memory efficiency of typescript/javascript array?

Tags: javascript, typescript, memory, push, memory-efficient

```
const ret1 = [];
const ret2 = [];

for (const points of pointsList) {
    ret1.push({ x: points.right.x, y: points.right.y});
    ret2.unshift({ x: points.left.x, y: points.left.y});
}
```

Push seems not that memory efficiency, is there any way to improve it?

Update:

I think to improve it is not from push but to use float32array, any advice?

Comment: What makes you feel that it is inefficient?

Comment: How is it not memory efficient? You're allocating a bunch of objects here. Did you mean to alias your existing objects? Did you mean to pre-allocate the array? `push` does allocate space in the array but that's just what happens when you put objects in an array. Unrelated topic: I can say `ret2.unshift` is slow because it's O(n^2) in a loop like this. Use `push` instead, then `reverse()` at the end.

Comment: @ggorlen Does pre-allocate the array makes this better?

Comment: I'm sorry but I have basically no idea what you're trying to accomplish, what the problem is exactly, and so forth, so it's hard/impossible to offer much of anything in the way of advice. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
const ret1 = pointsList.map(({right: {x,y}}) => ({x,y}));
const ret2 = pointsList.reverse().map(({left: {x,y}}) => ({x,y}));
```

Comment: That's a nice and legible solution, definitely an improvement, although it's a bit too fancy for me: it requires deep knowledge of JavaScript to parse it. However, the intention is obvious at first glance, so it's OK for me. But: why do you think it's more memory-efficient? I doubt it is, so I'm looking forward to your explanation. It's an honest and curious question: convince me!

Comment: Also maybe add an explanation. The community recieves answers more positively if that is done.